# Node Express fail load css and js

Tags: express, ejs

this is my folders:

```
/app
    └── models
        └── ...
    └── node_module
        └── ...
    └── routes
        └── ...
    └── public
        └── css
        └── js
    └── views
        └── unites
            └── new.js
            └── show.js
            └── edit.js
```

So, when I go on //mysiteweb/new my logs look like this:

```
GET /maitre-unites-new 304 4ms
GET /css/bootstrap.css 304 3ms
GET /js/bootstrap.js 304 2ms
```

But when I go on //mysiteweb/show my logs look like this:

```
GET /maitre-unites-show/52b46d81ddd1086615000001 304 2ms
GET /maitre-unites-show/css/bootstrap.css 404 2ms
GET /maitre-unites-show/js/bootstrap.js 404 1ms
GET /maitre-unites-show/images/unites/batiment1.jpeg 404 2ms
```

I don't understand why, my syntax is the same:

```
/*
 * GET New unit.
 */
    app.get('/maitre-unites-new', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res){
      Unites.find({}, function (err, unites) {
        res.render('unites/new', {
          unites: unites,
          user : req.user,
          title : ' Que voulez vous créer Maitre Du Jeu'
        });
      });
    });   
/*
 * GET show unit.
 */

    app.get('/maitre-unites-show/:id', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res){
      Unites.findById(req.params.id, function (err, unites) {
        res.render('unites/show', {
          unites: unites,
          user : req.user,
          title : ' Que voulez vous créer Maitre Du Jeu'
        });
      });
    });
```

my views news.js:

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
<% script('js/bootstrap.js') -%>
<% stylesheet('css/bootstrap.css') -%>

      <!-- Jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1><%= title + ' ' %><code><%= user.username %></code></h1>
          <p style="text-align:center;">Ho Créateur ! Inventez-nous comme toutes choses en cet univers.</p>
          <p>
            <a href="/maitre-aide" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">aide &raquo;</a>
            <a href="/maitre-de-jeu" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">retour &raquo;</a>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3>Créez une Unité:</h3>
          <form method='post' action='/maitre-unites-new'>

            <div>
            <label>Nom:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
            </div>

            <div>
            <label>Avatar:</label>
            <input type="text" name="avatar"/><br/>
            </div>

            <div>
              <label>Description:</label>
              <textarea name="description" row="5" cols="50"></textarea>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <%= unites.name %>

                <h2>Inclure d'autres unités dans celle-ci:</h2>
            <% if (unites && unites.length !=0) { %>
              <div>
                  <% for (var index in unites) { %>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<%= unites[index].unit %>" value="<%= unites[index]._id %>"> <%= unites[index].name %> |
                  <% } %>
              </div>
            <% } else { %>
              <div>
                no document exist
              </div>
            <% } %>

            <hr>

                <h2>Inclure cette unité dans d'autres unités:</h2>
            <% if (unites && unites.length !=0) { %>
              <div>
                  <% for (var index in unites) { %>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<%= unites[index].unit %>" value="<%= unites[index]._id %>"> <%= unites[index].unit %> |
                  <% } %>
              </div>
            <% } else { %>
              <div>
                no document exist
              </div>
            <% } %>


            <input type="submit" value="Save">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Site footer -->
      <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

my views show.js:

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
<% script('js/bootstrap.js') -%>
<% stylesheet('css/bootstrap.css') -%>

      <!-- Jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1><%= title + ' ' %><code><%= user.username %></code></h1>
      <p style="text-align:center;">Ho Créateur ! Inventez-nous comme toutes choses en cet univers.</p>
          <p>
            <a href="/maitre-aide" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">aide &raquo;</a>
            <a href="/maitre-de-jeu" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">retour &raquo;</a>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= unites.name %>
          <img src="images/unites/<%= unites.avatar %>.jpeg">
          <%= unites.description %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Site footer -->
      <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

This is my [repo.git](https://github.com/Sampistaroy/GW)
Why I get this /maitre-unites-show/images.... and not /images... ?

Comment: Did you declare a static folder for your public/static files? e.g. something like "app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));" in your app?

Comment: yes
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: You need to show your views.

Comment: I edited the post for add my views but they are the same. I make show.js with my views new.js

Comment: please, it's not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.  The error is caused by the fact that your `show` route has extra path component `/:id`, and your routes in the views are relative, so they are searched from the current URL, which is different:

```
new     ->    /
show    ->    /maitre-unites-show/
```

All you need to do is to make your paths absolute in the view:

```ejs
<% layout('layout') -%>
<% script('/js/bootstrap.js') -%>
<% stylesheet('/css/bootstrap.css') -%>
```

Comment: I can't fix it in other wise ?

Comment: There are numerous ways to fix it otherwise, but you must be working under some constraints, unknown to us, if the simplest and basically correct solution is not satisfactory.